# Swift- Cannot invoke '-' with an argument list of type (NSNumber , NSTimeinterval)

Tags: swift, nsnumber, nstimeinterval

i am trying to get the current time passes from certain point from the starting point of the app.

```
var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
     var currentTime: NSNumber = 0

    for var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        if i == 99 {
            currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
            println(i)
        }

    }
    var elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime
    println(Double(elapsedTime))
}
```

and i get this error :

```
Cannot invoke '-' with an argument list of type '(@!Value NSNumber, @!Value NSTimerinerval)
```

i understand it's something with the type i jutt cant figure it out, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startTime` is a `NSTimeInterval`, which is not the same thing as `NSNumber`, which is what you declared `currentTime` to be at the top of that function.

Change your declaration of `currentTime` to:

```
 var currentTime: NSTimeInterval = 0
```

Comment: The error `Cannot invoke 'yourMethodName' with an argument list of type....` will also be presented when you try to call an instance method from a class method.